# Can you rank entites by priority in Wit.ai?

Tags: wit.ai

Is there a way to prioritize Wit.ai entities? For example, sometimes a free-text entity is extracted even though an exact match keyword from another entity is available. Or is training this specific example my only option?

I'm having trouble understanding in which order are the trait, free-text and keyword entities extracted. Is there a document explaining the extraction process?

Comment: hi, you solved this??